# Handle lost connection during request

Tags: swift, reachability

I have an application were I make a request, before I make the request I do this

```
if Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork() != true {
    return
}
```

Then I do the request if the user is connected to the network, but I have noticed one thing if I make a request when I have wifi and then the wifi is lost and the user goes back to 3G/4G the app crashes.

Any suggestions of how to handle this type of issue?

Comment: can you post the stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

With limited information provided here, I would include error handling for this scenario so if connection lost, you would throw error and display your custom message to user. If you provide scenario, I can help you with specific answer.